# Master-Detail application : image on top of navigation bar

Tags: ios7, xcode5, master-detail

I am using a Master-detail application in which i need to put a unified picture on top of both navigation bars. I read practically every entry online and no luck..any ideas? 
**Actual navigation bars** : 
[image: Actual Navigation bar]

**Desired Nav bar**  :

[image: Desired NavBAr]

thank you

Comment: Describe more about your problem. What do you mean by "i need to put a unified picture on top of both navigation bars"? It will be better to understand if you give your sample code here.

Comment: @Tulon i need to remove the divider between the master and detail view  so i can access the upper bar and put a picture starting from the master and ending with the detail view controller

Comment: Provide your code to make it clear what & how exactly you trying to accomplish it.